# How to change hotkeys on Huion H610Pro graphics tablet?

Tags: shortcut-keys, tablet

I have attempted to use my Huion tablet on Ubuntu and several Ubuntu based distributions, and while the sensitivity and everything else work perfectly fine, the buttons on the side of the tablet aren't mapped correctly.

For instance, the the top button is supposed to be undo (so when you press it, it is supposed to input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>), but for some reason, when pressing it, it inputs <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. As you can imagine, that is certainly not helpful. All of the buttons are mapped in similar, useless configurations.

How do I remap the buttons?

Comment: You tagged this 'wacom'? It's an entirely different brand, might want to change that. Also, I had this exact same issue before when I used Huion and it seems to be entirely hopeless, just a warning.